# Storing a lambda in a variable in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm writing some code in C# to call a method that takes a callback. The method being called takes a callback as an optional parameter.

In this case I don't really need a callback for production purposes, but I'd like to put a Debug.Log in while I'm developing so I'm throwing in a lambda to log the results.

*(Note that I fully understand this isn't necessary, I can just do the log in the called method, but this question is more about me learning how to do things in c# than practicality)*

```
WebUtilities.instance.PushExperimentDataToApi(experimentType, formData, result => Debug.Log(result));
```

This works fine, but I'd like to pull that debug log out into a variable and pass in the variable instead. In other languages that I'm used to (dynamic) I could do something like:

```
let debug = string => console.log(string)
myClass.myMethod(arg1, arg2, debug)
```

And from looking around it seems like I may be able to accomplish the same thing with tuples, but I haven't quite figured out how.

Is there a way to do this? Again, I know this isn't necessary or practical in this case, I'm just using this as an example to better understand the language while building a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), and in particular the [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1):

```
Action<string> debug = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
```

and then the following will work as you expect:

```
myClass.myMethod(arg1, arg2, debug)
```

where `myMethod` is declared as follows:

```
public void myMethod(SomeType arg1, SomeType arg2, Action<string> debug) 
{
    … 
    debug("something");
    …
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1) delegate for that

```cs
Action<string> debug = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

And invoke it like `debug("test");` or `debug.Invoke("test");`. You can also it pass to `myMethod` to invoke inside it.

`myMethod` in this case should accept an `Action<string> debug` parameter

```cs
void myMethod(object arg1, object arg2, Action<string> debug)
{
    ...
    debug("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling method with anonymous lambda.");
        do
        {
            Foo((string name, object data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + data);
            });
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling method with null logger.");
            Foo();
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);


        Console.WriteLine("Calling method with delegate.");
        do
        {
            Foo(Logger);
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }

    // Example exercising the Action<T1, T2, ...> delegate per accepted answer
    static void Foo(Action<string, object> logger = null)
    {
        int data = _random.Next(1, 100);
        logger?.Invoke("Random Number", data);
    }

    static void Logger(string name, object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + ":" + data);
    }

    // Sample data generator
    static readonly Random _random = new Random();
}
```

Where console output might be:

```
Calling method anonymous lambda.
Random Number=24
Random Number=76
Random Number=11
Calling method with null logger.
Calling method with null logger.
Calling method with null logger.
Calling method with null logger.
Calling method with delegate.
Random Number:37
Random Number:74
Random Number:25
Random Number:82
```

Comment: Hmm, not completely. I was looking for an equivalent to an implementation that I was already familiar with in a different language, but this is still helpful to look :) There are some structures and implementations in here that I haven't seen yet in c#. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm happy to see that while I was typing furiously you got your solution in a more simple fashion and it's good that you marked the one you did as an answer. Really, this is just 3 variations of that. As others pointed out, the key to this sample is the use of Action<string, object> as the argument to Foo.